# Pulling out specific files in a directory based on unique file names and reading them in with read_wav in R

Tags: r, for-loop, audio

I have >1000 audio files in one directory that I have been tagging for bird calls and entering the data into excel.

Once I read in this data, I filtered out covariates of interest and made separate data frames. Basically, I have about 45 files I want to analyse separately with read_wav.

I'm not sure how to create a for loop to look into a certain directory '/all_SMP' and pull out these 45 files from a list of >1000.

I've created a list "list.clean", however my current forloop only lists every file in that folder (>1000 files)

```
for(i in c(list.clean)){
  raw.path <- paste0("../02_Working/SMP_SM4/SMP_15sec/all_AR_SMP")
  wav.list <- list.files(path="../02_Working/SMP_SM4/SMP_15sec/all_AR_SMP",
                         pattern="*.wav",
                         recursive=TRUE)
```

I'm quite a novice with R as I'm sure you can tell.

I want to read_wav on the 45 files and use the 'analyze' function on each file

```
audio1 <- analyze(sample1,samplingRate=24000, cutFreq=c(800,8000))
```

Hope this makes sense!

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Did you rename or do anything that distinguishes the 45 from the 1000, even down to what might be distinctive within the (ugh) excel files, such that they might be indexed as different from the others?

Comment: Hey Chris. Na I didn't. It involved me going through the spectrogram of each file in a program called song scope. Then I would write covariates of interest in excel. E.g., Penguin presence, Wind, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In `list.files` the parameter `pattern` is a regular expression.
So, for your case should be `pattern=".*\\.wav$"` (and it's case sensitive).

Alternatively and easier, you can use `fs::dir_ls(glob = "*.wav")`.